# How to treat object with **ALMOST ZERO** probability

Tags: probability

Eight random lines are constructed in the plane.

Compute the expected number of intersections.

I was thinking $28$, because that's the number of intersections of $8$ lines such that no three lines intersect at a single point and no two lines have the same slope.

And I know the answer is no less, because the probability of three lines intersecting is *almost zero* and the probability of two lines with the same slope is *almost zero*.

But is **almost zero** allowed to be treated as zero?

Comment: Why is probability of three lines intersecting almost  $0$?

Comment: Unless you are working with a very perverse probability distribution on lines, the probably that three independently chosen lines concur **is** zero, etc.

Comment: What is meant by "almost zero"? Events can be labeled as "almost sure" which means that their complement has (exactly) probability zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that three lines are concurrent, or that two lines are parallel, is not *almost zero*: it is actually *zero*. When we are dealing with continuous distributions, zero probability does not mean impossibility. Events with zero probability can, and do, happen.

Comment: similar to an infinitesimal?

Comment: Although the word *infinitesimal* can be given a meaning in an extension of the real numbers, as treated in what is known as Nonstandard Analysis, you would be well advised to disregard such concepts until you have mastered ordinary real analysis. The ill-founded introduction of infinitesimals by Leibniz, three centuries ago, has been confusing students ever since. Only with the invention of nonstandard analysis by Abraham Robinson in the 1960s was a proper framework for such ideas formulated.

Comment: Without some explanation your reply will make no sense for the non-initiated. And is mostly useless for the ones that already know (the exception being the ones that forgot that they knew)

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires: If the OP does not understand my reply, he can at least get from it the take-home message "forget about infinitesimals". If you can provide a better reply, then please do so.